# Split column value based on comma present in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table called Test with below values

```
ID Name Description
1  Xyz   Mumbai,Delhi
```

I want Sql  query which will give output as below

```
ID Name Description
1  Xyz   Mumbai
1  Xyz   Delhi
```

Comment: Shame on whoever it was who stored comma separated data.

Comment: @jarlh could you please help me in getting solution of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` with `'[^,]+'` pattern as second argument to split the comma seperated string

```
with tab( ID, Name, Description ) as
(
 select 1,'Xyz','Mumbai,Delhi' from dual
)
select ID, Name, 
       regexp_substr(Description,'[^,]+',1,level)
       as Description
  from tab 
 connect by level <= regexp_count(Description,',')+1;

ID  NAME   DESCRIPTION
--  ----   -----------
1   Xyz    Mumbai
1   Xyz    Delhi
```